# Some example on Google Drive Real time collaboration API for Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Could you pliz give me some links of integrating real time collaboration of Google drive in android. 
I saw all the videos and visited stack overflow and YouTube but no gains so far. am building an app that requires group collaboration on the same document so i need to integrate real time collaboration API but i have not yet achieved that.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the docs you will see that the realtime api is for use only from a,javascript browser app, not android app

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, but is with Javascript [Example](https://github.com/googledrive)

With android  can not do it.